# Aurelia dynamically bound variable with template string

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I am trying to set the dynamic `id` of a component within a component.

So the child component has a bindable `uniqueId` property.
The parent component has its own `uniqueId` which I am trying to keep into the child component's `uniqueId`, as such sort of following BEM convention:

```
<text-input-editor repeat.for="boxSide of boxSides"
   uniqueId.bind="box-editor-${uniqueId}__${boxSide}-input"></text-input-editor>
```

But this gives me the following error: `unconsumed token {` (abridged).

I tried with using the `<let></let>` element as in https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements#declarative-computed-values but that didn't work either.

I am not sure how to do this in the view, as I would rather not handle this at the controller's level (this is just one of many components in that view).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming uniqueId has a value in your viewmodel, as the expression already has a ".bind" format, this would be:

```
<text-input-editor repeat.for="boxSide of boxSides"
   uniqueId.bind="'box-editor-' + uniqueId + '__' + boxSide + '-input'"></text-input-editor>
```

Otherwise, it could be:

```
<text-input-editor repeat.for="boxSide of boxSides"
   uniqueId="box-editor-${uniqueId}__${boxSide}-input"></text-input-editor>
```

A working version can be reviewed at:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-dust-b7dgt?file=/src/app.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I had tried the second option and it didn't work either. My problem was actually with the camelCasing of uniqueId. Moving to snakeCase fixed it. Going to post too.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't try specifically Cristián Ormazábal's answer but I fixed my problem by changing `uniqueId` to `unique-id`:

```
<text-input-editor repeat.for="boxSide of boxSides"
  unique-id="box-editor-${uniqueId}__${boxSide}-input""
></text-input-editor>
```